# I'm looking for a simple splitView macOS template in swift, who can provide a direction?

Tags: swift, macos, macos-catalina, nssplitviewcontroller

I'm experienced with iOS development in objective C and swift.
Now I want to build a simple macOS application for personal use and when thinking about the user interface i want basically a sidebar with menu links and a right pane with the content.
I've been playing with NSSplitViewController and the basics are working.
However, let's say we have three menu items in our left sidebar e.g. Home Dashboard and Settings.
The default one showing on the right is the HomeViewController, which i can do.
Now when i click on Dashboard or Settings, I want the right part to load the DashboardViewController or the SettingsViewController and replace the HomeViewController. When i click Home, the HomeViewController is replacing the previous one.

So I was thinking I need to replace the viewController of one of the NSSplitViewItems (index 1) but can't make it work also it of course need to load the NSView for it from either the storyboard or a NIB.

Who can provide a working example please?

Answer (score 0):

In macOS you use the NavigationView to get a split view where you can select items in the left side bar, which then will be displayed in the right detailed view. You can see it working in this code, that was presented at WWDC 2021. [Building a great Mac App with SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/building_a_great_mac_app_with_swiftui)

Comment: What makes you think that this is a SwftUI topic?

Comment: @El Tomato, you're right. It might not be a SwiftUI topic. The question has been updated with more info. Therefore the answer is also obsolete.